# Check if UIView has a property

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

My project is being build for Unit Tests using CircleCI and it uses **XCode 8**. The following code crashes since it uses a property `safeAreaLayoutGuide` of `UIView` which doesn't exist in **iOS 10 SDK** even after having a check for **iOS 11**.

```
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        make.top.equalTo(testView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top)
    }
```

`testView` is a `UIView`. We are adding constraint to a navigation bar here. Is there a better way to check if UIView has this particular property available? `safeAreaLayoutGuide` is not `Optional`.

> Error Message :  value of type 'UIView' has no member
>   'safeAreaLayoutGuide'

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Using availability is the suggested way of checking for different platform in Swift. If you were in Objective C there are others, like checking for responds to selector or for the existence of a particular class in the SDk. But in case SWift You’re doing it totally right and in the standard way using #available

Comment: @aaron I added the error message

Comment: If it's using XCode8, does it actually have the iOS 11 SDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CircleCI would fail the build at `if #available(iOS 11, *)`. I would say upgrade to XCode 9 with your circle.yml file. Until then use the toplayoutguide of the view's view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use respondsToSelector as UIView still conforms to NSObjectProtocol:

```
if testView.responds(to: #selector(safeAreaLayoutGuide)) {
    make.top.equalTo(testView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `safeAreaLayoutGuide` you should use **Xcode 9+** only.
Because `safeAreaLayoutGuide` is `UIView` property which is added in **ios11 SDK** onwards.

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) { 
  print("for iOS 11 User")
} else {
  print("for iOS < 11 user")
}
```

The above check in `if` condition is mainly used for those user who are on **iOS11** & on `else` part the code will be for those user who are running with lower version like **iOS10**.

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)